# Specify a party-subclass/type in Corda

Tags: corda

I'm trying to program a CorDapp and I would like to know if there is the possibility to specify the type of a Party (for example Bank, Industry, Investor) in order to allow specific actions only by a particular Party type.

Like the use-case where only a Bank-type node can create a Loan and not a Investor-type or Industry-type.

I was thinking to create a subclass to Party, like BankParty etc. but the compiler says it is not possible because the Party class is final.

```
class BankParty() : Party {}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Similar question got asked 9 months later https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139648/in-corda-how-can-nodes-be-assigned-public-roles

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the same use case. One possible solution is to use the advertisedServices to differentiate the node/party types. We create our own custom ServiceType(s) and use them in the deployNodes gradle task. That way, we can query the networkMap to find out what nodes provide what services. 
Again, I'd like to hear from the Corda core team about the above approach or any other approaches.

\Sean