# In Corda, how can nodes be assigned public roles?

Tags: corda

I have written a CorDapp where I want to treat counterparty nodes differently based on their "role".

For example, I may want to check that a counterparty node has the "cash issuer" role before requesting cash issuance from them.

What's the best way to define public node roles in this way?

Comment: not the best way but we can go the Oracle way. each node can have a corda service that at the time of starting up i.e. in it's init method or constructor (by now I've access to service hub ) initiates a send/receive flow with the Oracle. to store it's role info. and other nodes can ask the oracle for it's role before initiating the flow. It does include an unnecessary headache to call the oracle each time before starting the flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Corda 3, there isn't built-in support for this feature. Support is expected to be added in a future release.

In the meantime, there are several workarounds:

- Using an oracle, as Kid101 mentions above. The oracle would store role information that could be queried by nodes
- The roles could be retrieved via a HTTP call within the flow - see the [Flow HTTP sample](https://github.com/corda/flow-http)
- The roles could be stored in the node's database and retrieved within the flow - see the [Flow DB sample](https://github.com/corda/flow-db)
- Each node could have a flow pair that returns the node's role
- The roles could be hardcoded in a configuration file installed on each node - see [How to provide a CorDapp with custom config in Corda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500297/how-to-provide-a-cordapp-with-custom-config-in-corda)
- The roles could be hardcoded in the CorDapp's flows