# Corda nodes role or nodes categorization

Tags: corda

I have a requirement of identifying a pool/set of nodes in the Flow on basis of their assigned role, So that the transactions can be sent to all nodes of a particular role/type.

For example:

- A node (Type 1)
- B node (Type 1)
- C node (Type 2)
- D node (Type 2)

Than, if I pass Type 2 in the flow, than I should be able to get the List of Parties/Node with that Type (i.e. C,D).

Is it possible? If yes, how? and where can I define the nodes type, maybe as some suffix in node name?

> One possible hacky way I have in mind is, set prefix in every node and
>   then get List of nodes, extract name and identify according to it. But
>   it will be required in every flow initiation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Corda, how can nodes be assigned public roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139648/in-corda-how-can-nodes-be-assigned-public-roles)

Comment: I have gone through that answer, but none of the approach fits best. Few of them increases the overhead and for rest of them, I am unsure how to implement. Would be helpful if someone could recommend better way for it..

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no better answer at this time. If you're having trouble implementing one of those patterns, please raise a separate question.

Comment: @Joel, Thanks will evaluate all the options and raise specific question if required.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better solution to serve your purpose with the fewer overheads.

If you are expecting the no. of nodes and roles to be changed dynamically, a proper way would be to retrieves the roles (whether using an oracle or not) and cache it.
Then write a separate flow to trigger updates it.

If not, you can just hardcode it in the config file.